# How to make array from variable and join with another string - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables

So I have a variable `$family`.

```
$family = "mom dad sister brother";
```

I have to make an array `$f` from variable `$family`. Something like this

```
$f = array("mom", "dad", "sister", "brother");
```

Next thing that I have is `$nice_family = "is nice"`;

Desired result : mom is nice, dad is nice, sister is nice, brother is nice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is not a request site. You can read more about how to ask a good question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `$f = explode(' ', $family);` is a good start.... [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$family = "mom dad sister brother";
$f = explode(' ', $family);
$nice = ' is nice';
echo $nice_family = implode($nice.', ' ,$f).$nice;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$family = "mom dad sister brother";
$f = explode(' ', $family);
$result = array_map(function($val) { return $val . ' is nice';}, $f);

print_r($result);
Array
(
[0] => mom is nice
[1] => dad is nice
[2] => sister is nice
[3] => brother is nice
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php) to create the desired array:

```
$f = explode(' ', $family);
```

Then you could use [implode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php) to get the desired result string:

```
echo implode(' ' . $nice_family . ', ', $f) . ' ' . $nice_family . '.';
```